# Jquery - webservices

Tags: jquery, web-services

JQuery is meant for writing client side scripts. I read, we can call webservices in JQuery. Can you please give me a scenario need of calling webservices on the client side. thanks !

Comment: e.g. you want to display stock prices or weather information from a web service on your site - or **countless** other things you can do with a web service....

Comment: but we can call from server side code as well. Can you pls tell me advantage of call from client side. [sorry, I am a little bit new to programming]thanks !

Comment: For example - when you need lots of calls to webservices. Doing all calls from the server side would make your page load veeery long. Instead, you can fire the calls after the page has loaded, display loading indicators, etc. And it's only a one scenario of a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple ajax call via GET :

**On client:**

*PHP: (ex: view.php)*

```
<span>value:</span><span id="ajaxValue"></span>
```

*jQuery: (ex: view.php)*

```
$.get('ws/getValueById.php?id=<?php echo $currentId ?>', function(data) {
  $('#ajaxValue').html(data);
});
```

**On server:**

*PHP (ex: ws/getValueById.php)*

```
function getValueById($id) {
  // database fetch
}
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) die('missing parameter id');
die (getValueById($_GET['id']));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario**-Assuming,you want to retrieve the country list in the drop down by making the ajax call to a web service through JQuery.

Below is the Example Of JQuery call from Spring thymleaf template

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    $("document").ready(function() {
        $("select#country").change(function() {
            var selectedCountry = $("#country option:selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                url : "/TestApplication/selectedCountry/" + selectedCountry,
                cache : false,
                timeout : 600000,
                success : function(data) {
                    $('#feedback').html(data);

                }

            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

In the above example a service is called(/TestApplication/selectedCountry/) to retrieve the set of countries.